# Harvesting from SQL Server to GeoNetwork?

Tags: sql-server, web-service, geonetwork

I am using a Geonetwork Harvester, configured to pull from a ArcSDE, V3.2.0. of Geonetwork. The server I'm trying to harvest from is a sql server and am getting a "No instance running on server" error, even though I can connect to the SQL Server through ArcCatalog. Here's the error message:

> 0 Unknown Host - YK54-vweb02t\sql1  NO INSTANCE RUNNING ON SERVER.
>   2016-10-12 14:29:31,533 WARN  [Geonetwork] - Raised exception while
>   harvesting from : Geonetwork (ArcSDEHarvester) 2016-10-12 14:29:31,533
>   WARN  [Geonetwork] -  (C) Class   : ExceptionInInitializerError
>   2016-10-12 14:29:31,533 WARN  [Geonetwork] -  (C) Message : null
>   2016-10-12 14:29:35,760 WARN  [geonetwork.resources] - Resource not
>   found images/harvesting/[], default resource returned:
>   /images/harvesting/[] 2016-10-12 14:29:39,496 WARN 
>   [geonetwork.resources] - Resource not found images/harvesting/[],
>   default resource returned: /images/harvesting/[] 2016-10-12
>   14:31:02,818 WARN  [geonetwork.resources] - Resource not found
>   images/harvesting/[], default resource returned: /images/harvesting/[]
>   2016-10-12 14:31:06,104 WARN  [geonetwork.resources] - Resource not
>   found images/harvesting/[], default resource returned:
>   /images/harvesting/[] 2016-10-12 14:31:08,755 WARN 
>   [geonetwork.resources] - Resource not found images/harvesting/[],
>   default resource returned: /images/harvesting/[]

I'm fairly new to developing and don't quite know where to look.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you harvesting from the database? Are you using a GeoNetwork harvester? Which one? What configuration?